# Minikube: Error starting host: Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized

Tags: kubernetes, virtualization, minikube

I get an error :" Error starting host:  Temporary Error: Error configuring auth on host: OS type not recognized" when trying to start minikube on windows 10. I have checked VT-x is enabled and I still can't run minikube, can any one help please

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `minikube delete`
2. Delete `C:\Users\username\.minikube` folder.
3. `minikube start` again.

If this will not help I can advice you install [minikube](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Minikube) or [kubernetes-cli](https://chocolatey.org/packages/kubernetes-cli) using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install).

Comment: and yes, If my answer will not work for you - can you share any details about your current configuration. I mean Windows version, hypervisor type and way you are launching minikube, docker version